# TeamCity REST API Error: Error has occurred during request processing (Not Acceptable)

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I tried to receive in .NET information about TeamCity build. All works fine, except one: I tried to get build name, using request to REST API.

Here is my request:

```
https://myteamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<build_id>/name
```

And here is my error: Error has occurred during request processing (Not Acceptable).
Error: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
Not supported request. Please check URL, HTTP method and transfered data are correct.

In browser I received correct plain text information. What's wrong with REST API? All another requests work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Accept` header might cause the problem, try changing it to `Accept: text/plain` or removing it.

For example, when I request

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:buildId/name --user user:pass
```

I'm getting the same error, but the name is returned after changing value of the header to `text/plain`

```
curl -H "Accept: text/plain" http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:buildId/name --user user:pass
```

or after removing the header from the request

```
curl http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:buildId/name --user user:pass
```